# How to use Lead Automation functionality in Marketing Campaigns module Odoo V9?

Tags: crm, odoo-9, lead

Can someone explain me how marketing campaigns works in odoo9?

After installing module there is one menu displayed called "**Lead Automation**". There is no documentation related to this module.

I will be happy if someone explain me the whole process of marketing campaign module and how it is connected with CRM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several blogs from where you can get some idea about the flow of the module.

http://bloopark.de/en_US/blog/the-bloopark-times-english-2/post/odoo-marketing-apps-vs-mailchimp-319

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the link. Can you please let me know how the campaign statistics is generated?

Comment: https://support.whatcounts.com/hc/en-us/articles/204668945-Campaign-Statistics-Report